# Сессия asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookie, сессия

Имеется проект на технологии asp.net. Есть контролер, в нём два метода: **[httpGet]** и **[httpPost]**. В post принимаю данные из view и выполняю хранимку. Во view просто поля для заполнения, нужно сделать так чтобы после перезагрузки страницы все значения в полях оставались. Почитал, что можно реализовать это с помощью сессии или куков. Как сохранять значения разобрался: **Session["name_Session"] = _nameObject**; но не понимаю куда его нужно потом передать и где использовать чтобы всё сохранялось. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно это сделать.

Comment: можно ViewBag использовать..проще

Comment: Сессия не для хранения, сессия - это оперативные данные, которые нужны в течении текущей... эээ... сессии

Comment: return View(model)

Answer (score 0):

**Object _nameObject = new Object();**
**Session["name_Session"] = _nameObject;** - сохранили значение
**Object _nameObject = Session["name_Session"] as Object;** - получить сохраненное значение в любом методе класса контроллера